# What is the method to hide files in multiple images with batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm tried this command:

- copy /b *.png + test.zip

but it didn't work

Comment: What is an image for you? What do you want to hide? What do you expect? I can't see anything multiple in your question. Currently I can't understand your question at all

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one image at a time, and you need to specify an output file in order for `copy` to actually produce a file. If you want to add the zip file to every image in the directory, you can loop over the list of png files with a `for` loop.

```
for %%A in (*.png) do copy /b "%%~A" +test.zip "output_%%~nxA"
```